# Keep all the duplicates in a dataframe column EXCEPT the first one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

I have a `dataframe` with client ids, payment date and amount paid.

|  | client_id | payment_date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 067858 | 2021-05-30 | 140.000000 |
| 1 | 168226 | 2021-05-30 | 150.000000 |
| 2 | 141424 | 2021-05-31 | 100.000000 |
| 3 | 141424 | 2021-06-01 | 150.000000 |
| 4 | 151525 | 2021-06-01 | 150.000000 |
| 5 | 168226 | 2021-06-02 | 115.000000 |
| 6 | 067858 | 2021-06-05 | 143.000000 |
| 7 | 151525 | 2021-06-07 | 82.000000 |

I need to keep all the duplicates on `client_id` except for the first one.

This is the desired output:

|  | client_id | payment_date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 141424 | 2021-06-01 | 150.000000 |
| 5 | 168226 | 2021-06-02 | 115.000000 |
| 6 | 067858 | 2021-06-05 | 143.000000 |
| 7 | 151525 | 2021-06-07 | 82.000000 |

I tried putting all client_ids in a `list`:

`list = df['client_id'].tolist()`

Then using `ne` and `idxmax` on the `dataframe` to get all the rows where an unique `client_id` appears first.

`first_rows = df.client_id.ne(list).idxmax().to_list()`

So I could get all the rows where a `client_id` first appears and then drop them from the main `dataframe`.

But I only got the error:

`ValueError: Lengths must be equal`

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and perform [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df[df['client_id'].duplicated()]
```

Output:

```
   client_id payment_date  value
3     141424   2021-06-01  150.0
5     168226   2021-06-02  115.0
6      67858   2021-06-05  143.0
7     151525   2021-06-07   82.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
mask = df.duplicated(subset=["client_id"], keep="first")
print(df.loc[mask])
```

Prints:

```
   client_id payment_date  value
3     141424   2021-06-01  150.0
5     168226   2021-06-02  115.0
6      67858   2021-06-05  143.0
7     151525   2021-06-07   82.0
```

Comment: I think OP wants to keep all the duplicates except the first ;)

Comment: @mozway Yup, `keep='first'` :)